# Last elements in 2D list rows are not changing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional list and I'm iterating over it to change the elements with whatever a user inputs.

The length of each row is determined by the key the user inputs and the amount of rows is determined by the the length of the message the user inputs (+ 1, because the first row is filled with ASCII values which needs to be there for other reasons)

For example, if I input "frank" as the key, and "how are you" as the message, I want to get the output of:

```
[[(ASCII values], ['h', 'o', 'w', 'a', 'r'], ['e', 'y', 'o', 'u', 0]
```

But instead I get:

```
[[(ASCII values], ['h', 'o', 'w', 'a', '0'], ['r', 'e', 'y', 'o', 0]
```

Here is the code:

```
def main():
    keyword = get_keyword()
    key_length = get_keyword_length(keyword)
    message = get_message()
    ascii_list = ascii_conversion(keyword, key_length)
    box = encryption_box(ascii_list, message, key_length)
    print(box)
    fill_letters(box, message, key_length)
    print(box)

# Gets the keyword to encrypt with.
def get_keyword():
    keyword = input("Enter the word you'd like to use for encryption (no duplicate letters): ").lower()
    return keyword

# Gets length of keyword
def get_keyword_length(keyword):
    key_length = len(keyword)
    return key_length

# Gets the message to encrypt and removes punctuation and spaces.
def get_message():
    message = input('Enter the message you want to encrypt: ').lower()
    message = message.replace("'", "").replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace("!", "").replace("?", "")\
    .replace(" ", "")
    return message

# Converts keyword to ASCII
def ascii_conversion(keyword, key_length):
    ascii_list = [0] * key_length
    index = 0
    for character in keyword:
        ascii_list[index] = ord(character)
        index += 1
    return ascii_list

# Creates 2D list with correct dimensions and fills first row with the ascii numbers.
def encryption_box(ascii_list, message, key_length):
    if len(message) % len(ascii_list) != 0:
        box = [[0] * len(ascii_list) for x in range(len(message)//(len(ascii_list))+2)]
    else:
        box = [[0] * len(ascii_list) for x in range(len(message)//(len(ascii_list))+1)]
    index = 0
    for number in ascii_list:
        box[0][index] = number
        index += 1
    return box

# Fill in the message in the remaining encryption box spaces.
def fill_letters(box, message, key_length):
    len_box = len(box)
    message = list(message)
    index = 0

    for r in range(1, len_box):
        for c in range(key_length - 1):
            box[r][c] = message[index]
            index += 1

main()
```

Looking at this:

```
for r in range(1, len_box):
    for c in range(key_length - 1):
        box[r][c] = message[index]
        index += 1
```

I feel like eventually box[r][c] will be box[1][4] and correspond to that last element, yet it remains 0. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you could use `list.append(element)` and you will not need something like `[0] * key_length` . And using comprehension list you could create `ascii_list` in one line `ascii_list = [ord(char) for char in keyword]`

Comment: Thanks furas. I always overlook list comprehensions since I don't use them often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range` has an exclusive upper bound, so the -1 can't be there.
After that you'll get an index-out-of-range for trying to access positions of the message that aren't there. Gotta stop the loop early when the end of the message is reached.

```
for r in range(1, len_box):
    for c in range(key_length):
        if index == len(message): break
        box[r][c] = message[index]
        index += 1
```